# How to replicate jquery animation sequence in vanilla js/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

As the title says, I would like to replicate the animation bellow. the jquery API https://api.jquery.com/toggle/ decibels this default behavior as so:

```
easing (default: swing)
Type: String
A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.
```

but I don't understand how the transition works. I have tried changing the opacity, translating the element, ect, but obviously no luck. If it is impossible to do this in a simple way without jquery, an answer for the transition effect without the toggle function is also acceptable (but not `hide()` and `show()` as I have already tried those and couldn't get it to work properly). And yes, I would prefer a swing transition if possible. any help is appreciated.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
$('#elem').toggle('.hide');
});
```

```css
.hide{
display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='elem' class= 'hide'>
easing text transion
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don´t know if I understood your question correctly but you want

```
document.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
$('#elem').toggle('.hide');
});
```

in normal JS?

You have two options: set an data attribute to #elem or you check if #elem has the class
.hide. But its easier to just add the css to the element

With data attribute:

```
<div id='elem' data-status='inv' class='hide'>
easing text transion
</div>
```

```
let toggleFunction = function() {
  let elem = document.querySelector('#elem');
  if (elem.dataset.status == "inv") {
    elem.className = "";
    elem.dataset.status = "vis";
  } else if (elem.dataset.status == "vis") {
    elem.className = "hide";
    elem.dataset.status = "inv";
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', toggleFunction);
```

Or with css:

```
<div id='elem' style='display: none;'>
easing text transion
</div>
```

```
let toggleFunction = function() {
  let elem = document.querySelector('#elem');
  if (elem.style.display == 'none') {
    elem.style.display = 'inherit';
  } else {
    elem.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', toggleFunction);
```

If you still want the animation:

```
<div id='elem' style='height: 0px;'>
easing text transion
</div>
```

```
#elem {
  transition: 1s ease-in-out all;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```
let toggleFunction = function() {
  let elem = document.querySelector('#elem');
  if (elem.style.height == '0px') {
    elem.style.height = '18px';
  } else {
    elem.style.height = '0px';
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', toggleFunction);
```

I hope I could help

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I am looking for the animation, not the actual toggle function.

Comment: just use the style attribute and set it to 0px. It works as I wrote it. You may have to fine tune the transiiton in css but its not that difficult: 1s is the time, ease-in-out the timing-function and all the property.

Answer (score 2):

You can toggle a class and use a css transition to do it

```js
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('elem').classList.toggle('no-height')
})
```

```css
#elem {
  max-height: 2em;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#elem.no-height {
  max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='elem'>
  easing text transion
</div>
```